# Django - filter by foreign key string

Tags: database, django, filter

main table:

```
class example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Item Name', max_length=200)
    color = models.ManyToManyField(Color)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    image = models.ImageField('Item Image',upload_to="example/images/")
```

Category table:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    catname = models.CharField('Category Name',max_length=100)
```

How can i query it while filtering the example table according to the category.

This didn't work out:

```
def list(request, cat):
    c = example.object.filter(category = cat)
```

What should i change to make this filtering work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Django's documentation on related lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
def list(request, cat):
    c = example.objects.filter(category__catname=cat)
```